# Pandas drop duplicated values followed one by another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
input_data = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'A'], 'stop_no': [1, 2,  2, 4, 5, 2]})
```

I want to remove the duplicated values in column 'stop_no', but only if they are located one after another. So the output should be

```
output_data = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B', 'A'],
        'stop_no': [1, 2, 4, 5, 2]})
```

I tried `.drop_duplicates()` but it seems to delete only first or last occasion

Comment: `df1 = df[df['stop_no'].ne(df['stop_no'].shift())]`